# How to load select dropdown menu itens after click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a select box with 7.000 itens in my WordPress, and I'd like that the options are only loaded after the user click, due to performance issues. I have no idea how to do it, because the code that generates the options I have is a mix of HTML and PHP.

```
<select class="chosen" name="tag-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="#">Select an artist</option>
    <?php dropdown_tag_cloud('number=0&order=asc'); ?>
</select>
```

The main function that I included in my functions.php file can be found [here](http://wphacks.com/how-to-display-wordpress-tags-dropdown-menu/). How can load the options after the user click?

Comment: Ajax is your friend in this case.

Comment: There is no way to do that only with PHP and HTML. You need Javascript (Ajax). I recommend the use of jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and also checkout the site about the change event https://api.jquery.com/change/. If you got familiar with jquery it will help you a lot with those things.

Comment: In my select box, the php function already gets all the options and populate it. Isn't there a way I can call the function only if the user click? Using javascript onclick event, or jQuery..?

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

Once the PHP script has run it sends the output to the client machine. So you can't call the function when the client clicks unless you use an AJAX call to another file.

So you need to move the function to it's own file. Maybe:

> get-select-options.php

Put your function in there and then the call to that function at the top as an echo:

```
<?php

     echo dropdown_tag_cloud('number=0&order=asc');

     function tag_cloud($parameters){
         return $stuff;
     }
?>
```

In your main file you can create a ajax call to get the results. Use [JQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```
<script>
    $('select[name=tag-dropdown]').click(function(){
        $.get('select-options.php', {}, function(r){
            $('select[name=tag-dropdown]').append(r);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I would add in a loading animation so the user knows to wait.

If you need to pass parameters to the function you can do so inside the ajax call:

```
$.get('select-options.php', {'number':3, 'order':'asc'}, function(r){});
```

and then in the PHP file you can use $_GET to retrieve the paramters

```
$number = $_GET['number'];
$order = $_GET['order'];
```

**EDIT:**

You could also populate a variable in JS with the PHP output on the same page and then update the select options on click.

**Important** The output of the "dropdown-tag-cloud" function must be a string for the way I have it written to work: *`(example: <option value="asdf">tag</option><option value="qwer">tag</option>)`*

```
<script>
    var options = '<?php echo dropdown_tag_cloud(0,"asc")'; ?>;

    $('select[name=tag-dropdown]').click(function(){
        $('select[name=tag-dropdown]').append(options);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I want to set it as answered, but I would need more help first. Do you want me to create a file named "get-select-options.php", and insert `<?php

     echo dropdown_tag_cloud('number=0&order=asc');

     function tag_cloud($parameters){
         return $stuff;
     }
?>` in it? And then I go to my functions.php and add `<script>
    $('select[name=tag-dropdown]').click(function(){
        $.get('select-options.php', {}, function(r){
            $('select[name=tag-dropdown]').append(r);
        });
    });
</script>`?

Comment: yes to the first part. The javascript goes wherever you want to populate your select html. So if that html exists in functions.php then yes put it there after the select html.

Comment: Is there a way not to have another php file? My template is getting heavy and I'd like to add it in another place for better speed.